# HBase- Delete multiple rows

Tags: hbase

I have a HBase table with millions of rows. I now want to delete around 70,000 rows from this table. For each of the row I have the complete rowkey needed.
So I can issue the following command:

```
delete 'tablename','rowkey'
```

But instead of running a delete command 70,000 times, is there any bulk operation I can use?
I'm on HBase 0.98.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Scan](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html) class of HBase Client Java API. This allows you to delete bulk amount of data easily.
I do have some sample code here in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519549/how-to-delete-recent-version-of-all-columns-based-on-rowkey-in-hbase/39571400#39571400).